# So how do I read the contents of a Google Drive file in App Script without the lines being reordered?

Tags: google-apps-script, blob, google-docs

So how do I read the contents of a Google Drive file in App Script without the lines being reordered?

So here is my situation :

- I have some files that have text content with file extensions of **.lua**
- I have copied them to my Google Drive

  - For some reason it thinks they are image files! This may be a cause of my main problems
- I am trying to read them in a script attached to a Google Spreadsheet

  ```
  function test_bug_readFile_linesInWrongOrder() {
      var fileId1 = "12-YLK6Lv5UYNZIgkr-u-DBviwLIOr1F2" // orig file .lua
      var fileId2 = "1fyvdHrc45Q_-G02XJ1ismCROKqcxyoPL" // test file shortened and .txt
      var fileId3 = "1uw7gG869_yIhpYh2vY2iKtUU5njBRrwA" // test file same as orig but .txt

      var file = DriveApp.getFileById( fileId1 )
      var fileBlob = file.getBlob()
      //  var fileBlob = file.getBlob().setContentType( "text/plain" )
      var raw = fileBlob.getDataAsString()
      Logger.log( raw.length )
      Logger.log( raw )
  }
  ```
- When I run this I get the contents of the file  but the lines are in the wrong order !! You can see the various behaviours by changing the parameter passed to the getFileById(...)

  - fileId1 was the original file and exhibits the error described below
  - fileId2 is a much smaller file and is a **.txt** but it does not misbehave and I get the lines in correct order
  - fileId3 is a copy of the original file but the file extension has been changed to **.txt** ( and the first line for clarity ). This also does not exhibit the error, but it does still show up as an image file

It seems that when the error occurs the lines with the same parent line and same indentation level change order, maybe based on some hash values. I tried copying the text in here but could not figure out he markup and the question is already long. :)

I have tried setting MIME types on the blob before I read them but that did not seem to do anything.
I have set the above three data files to be publicly readable, any problems let me know.

So how do you read the contents of a file / blob without google App Script "helpfully" reordering them for you ?

Thanks in advance for all the help

**Edit :**

Ok I have made a demo project :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i_VqYANrqE5FXEQxFAx4dbheEJ89I8MwGSDrxenwHtU
you need to let it load and then a menu will appear with title of "BugDemo". Once you have that just choose the only menu item in it and you should get a permission dialog. I realise  you may not want to give my code permission so I have included the code in the block below so you can make your own project and be sure that there is no extra back doors or anything.

```
"use strict";

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu( 'BugDemo' )
      .addItem( 'Read 3 Files and show first 10,000 chars', 'test_bug_readFile_linesInWrongOrder' )
    .addToUi()
}

function test_bug_readFile_linesInWrongOrder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  sh.clear()  

  var fileIds = ["12-YLK6Lv5UYNZIgkr-u-DBviwLIOr1F2", // orig file .lua
             "1fyvdHrc45Q_-G02XJ1ismCROKqcxyoPL", // test file shortened and .txt
             "1uw7gG869_yIhpYh2vY2iKtUU5njBRrwA"  // test file same as orig but .txt
            ]
  var fileDescs = ["original file",
             "much smaller file, also with .txt extension",
             "same as first file but with extension of .txt"
            ]

  for ( var col = 0; col < fileIds.length; col++ ) {
    var fileId = fileIds[col]
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById( fileId )
    var fileBlob = file.getBlob()
    var text = fileBlob.getDataAsString().slice( 0, 10000 )

    var r = sh.getRange( 1, col + 1, 1, 1 )
    r.setValue( fileId )
    r.offset( 1, 0, 1, 1 ).setValue( file.getName() )
    r.offset( 2, 0, 1, 1 ).setValue( fileDescs[col] )
    r.offset( 4, 0, 1, 1 ).setValue( text )
  }
}
```

Once you run this you should see three columns of data appear and the first column is the wrong one.

**Errors :**

1. You
   should see that it goes directly from **["$AccountWide"]** to **["SalesData"]** where as the data file has several other lines in it, as can be seen in the other 2 columns.
2. The deepest indented block with keys of : ( ["itemLink"], ["timestamp"], ["price"], ["wasKiosk"], ["buyer"], ["guild"], ["seller"], ["quant"], ["id"] ) are all there but in a different but consistent order.
3. The first column seems to somehow acquire a starting and ending {} that is not in the data file.

Is it possible that behind the scenes Google is using some Lua code and then that is doing a context sensitive parsing of the data ( understands the data structure ) and then gets re-serialized in a different order ?

Comment: Where / how are you checking that the file is an "image file"?

Comment: I would like to try to replicate your issue. So can you provide a sample file which has the issue in your question?

Comment: @tehhowch In Google drive when I right click on the file and do "View Details", it shows the type as Image

Comment: @Tanaike I have already made public the 3 data files mentioned in the question. The three file Id are in the question and you can access them directly with a link like the following
https://drive.google.com/file/d/<file-ID>
The file that exhibits the problem is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-YLK6Lv5UYNZIgkr-u-DBviwLIOr1F2  Hope that helps

Comment: @Mad G Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, it seems that there is no mimeType of ``lua`` at Google Apps Script. I think that the reason that the file icon becomes image might be this. But the content can be retrieved by ``getDataAsString()``. I checked ``raw``. But the values are the same between the result retrieved by Google Apps Script and the downloaded result. So can I ask you about the method for replication your situation? If I misunderstood it, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike - Thanks for trying :-) I have added a new block of info into the question under the heading of "Edit" with a working demo of the problem, hope it helps

Comment: @Mad G Thank you for replying and updating your question. In my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. So I proposed an other method for retrieving the file content as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Mad Can I ask you about your situation? If my proposal didn't resolve your issue, I have to apologize and modify or remove it, because I don't want to make other users confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see your shared Spreadsheet, it seems that `original file` is different from others. But when I run your script, the results from all file IDs are the same. I couldn't replicate your situation.

So although I cannot confirm whether this is the direct solution of your issue, in this modification, I used Drive API v3 instead of DriveApp for retrieving the file content.

#### Modified script:

```
function test_bug_readFile_linesInWrongOrder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  sh.clear()

  var fileIds = ["12-YLK6Lv5UYNZIgkr-u-DBviwLIOr1F2", // orig file .lua
                 "1fyvdHrc45Q_-G02XJ1ismCROKqcxyoPL", // test file shortened and .txt
                 "1uw7gG869_yIhpYh2vY2iKtUU5njBRrwA"  // test file same as orig but .txt
                ]
  var fileDescs = ["original file",
                 "much smaller file, also with .txt extension",
                 "same as first file but with extension of .txt"
                ]

  for ( var col = 0; col < fileIds.length; col++ ) {
    var fileId = fileIds[col]

    var file = DriveApp.getFileById( fileId );
//    var fileBlob = file.getBlob()
//    var text = fileBlob.getDataAsString().slice( 0, 10000 )

    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?alt=media&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); // Added
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); // Added
    var text = res.slice( 0, 10000 ); // Added

    var r = sh.getRange( 1, col + 1, 1, 1 )
    r.setValue( fileId )
    r.offset( 1, 0, 1, 1 ).setValue( file.getName() )
    r.offset( 2, 0, 1, 1 ).setValue( fileDescs[col] )
    r.offset( 4, 0, 1, 1 ).setValue( text )
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- I think that Lua code is not affected to Google Drive, because the mimeType of image is used for the Lua data when Lua file is uploaded to Google Drive, and also the correct mimeType of Lua cannot be set using `setContentTypeFromExtension()`.
- In your script, DriveApp is already used. So I think that the scope for using Drive API has already installed and also Drive API has already been enabled. If the error related to Drive API occurs, please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at API console.

#### Reference:

- [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

If this modification didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: I am accepting this as a workaround to get the contents of the file but the main issue remains and I have raised it as a bug with Google

Comment: @Mad G Thank you for replying and the additional information.